# How to replace a content in checkout magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to  replace a content in checkout  magento 2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **This Message Appear On This 2 File :-**

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

**In content.html Line no. 33 to 38**

```
<!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() === 1) -->
      <span translate="'Item in Cart'"/>
          <!--/ko-->
          <!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() > 1) -->
          <span translate="'Items in Cart'"/>
          <!--/ko-->
```

**In cart-items.html Line no. 12 And 14**

```
   <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() === 1"/>
   <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() > 1"/>
```

**You Can Override This File In Your Theme and After Changes This File. Use Following Code**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content -f

sudo php bin/magento c:f

sudo chmod -R 0777 generated/code/ pub/ var/
```